# Efficient replacement of x < i values in sparse array

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix

How would I replace values less than 4 with 0 in this array without triggering a `SparseEfficiencyWarning` and without reducing its sparsity?

```
from scipy import sparse
x = sparse.csr_matrix(
    [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [0, 0, 0, 2, 5]])
x[x < 4] = 0
x.toarray()  # verifies that this works
```

Note also that the sparsity between the initial version of `x` is 11 stored elements, which rises to 15 stored elements after doing the masking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manipulate the data array directly

```
from scipy import sparse
x = sparse.csr_matrix(
    [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [0, 0, 0, 2, 5]])

x.data[x.data < 4] = 0

>>> x.toarray()
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5]])

>>> x.data
array([0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 5])
```

Note that the sparsity is unchanged and there are zero values unless you run `x.eliminate_zeros()`.

```
x.eliminate_zeros()
>>> x.data
array([4, 4, 5, 5])
```

If for some reason you don't want to use a boolean mask & fancy indexing in numpy, you can loop over the array with numba:

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def _set_array_less_than_to_zero(array, value):
    
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] < value:
            array[i] = 0
```

This should also be faster than the numpy indexing by a fairly substantial degree.

```
array = np.arange(10)
_set_array_less_than_to_zero(array, 5)

>>> array
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: I hit a memory error when doing this; is there some way to reduce memory usage on the `x.data[x.data < i]` step?

Comment: The only reason that you'd have a memory error here is if `x.data` is copy-on-write or if the boolean `x.data < i` array can't be allocated. You could iterate over the array to change it instead of making a boolean mask and using indexing if it's `x.data < i` that's the problem, but its probably a copy on write issue, which you can only fix by changing other code that isn't here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the error is emerging from the boolean mask; how would I iterate over the array to effect the same masking?

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is to write a simple for loop to iterate over the array and JIT compile it with numba.